# SQL Server: Physical Memory and Arc Cursors

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I implemented a script recently that uses an update and search cursor on a large feature class database of over 20,000 records. This script runs nightly. This is an SQL Server database with an ArcSDE connection. However, the physical memory of the server (sqlserver.exe) has been running at over 86% and bogging down any edits that users want to make. Prior to this script, the server was running normally.

The script currently does not delete any cursors, and I'm wondering if this is causing a load up of information in the system. If so, how do I go about deleting the information?

Comment: be sure after your script finishes it drops the connection. and set to create a new connection in the start of your script

Comment: @Joe, that's how I have it as of now. I set up the database connection, then arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management() at the end

Comment: it runs nightly after office hours but when does it complete? before the next morning when users log in?

Comment: @Joe, that is correct, it starts and ends between 7:30PM-8PM

Comment: It would be a lot easier to offer help if you post the script.